# What is wrong with the following file writing code?

Tags: c, file, linked-list, access-violation

i have the following structure that i use to create a hash table for fingerprints

```
typedef struct fpinfo
{ 
   unsigned long chunk_offset;
   unsigned long chunk_length;
   unsigned char fing_print[33];
}fpinfo;
```

/*
 * The following defines one entry in the hash table.
 */

```
typedef struct Hash_Entry 
{
   struct Hash_Entry *next; /* Link entries within same bucket. */
   unsigned namehash;   /* hash value of key */
   struct fpinfo fp;
} Hash_Entry;

typedef struct Hash_Table 
{
   struct Hash_Entry **bucketPtr;   /* Buckets in the table */
   int numBuckets;
   int        buck_entry_count[64];//number of entries in each bucket
   int      size;       /* Actual size of array. */
   int      numEntries; /* Number of entries in the table. */
   int      mask;       /* Used to select bits for hashing. */
} Hash_Table;
```

I insert fingerprints into it using

```
int Hash_CreateEntry(Hash_Table *t, struct Hash_Entry he)
{
Hash_Entry *e;
const char *p;
int keylen;
struct Hash_Entry **hp;
unsigned long h = 0, g,i=0;

while ( i<5 ) 
 {
    h = ( h ) + he.fp.fing_print[i]++;
     g = h & 0xF0000000;
    h ^= g >> 24;
    h &= ~g;
    i++;
}

p =(const char*) he.fp.fing_print;
for (e = t->bucketPtr[h & t->mask]; e != NULL; e = e->next)
{
    if (e->namehash == h && strcmp((const char *)(e->fp).fing_print, p) == 0)
    {
        printf("\n%d \t%s",(e->fp).chunk_length,(e->fp).fing_print);
        return (1);
    }
}

if (t->numEntries >= rebuildLimit * t->size)
    WriteHTtoFile(t);
e = (Hash_Entry *)malloc(sizeof(*e) /*+ keylen*/);
hp = &t->bucketPtr[h & t->mask];
e->next = *hp;
*hp = e;
e->namehash = h;
strcpy((char *)(e->fp).fing_print, p);
t->numEntries++;
t->buck_entry_count[h & t->mask]++;
return (0);
}
```

The Code I used to write the HT to file is

```
static void   WriteHTtoFile(Hash_Table *t)
{
Hash_Entry *e, *next = NULL, **hp, **xp;
int i=0, mask;
    Hash_Entry **oldhp;
int oldsize;
FILE *htfile=fopen("htfile.txt","a");
system("cls");

for ( hp = t->bucketPtr;t->bucketPtr!=NULL;hp=t->bucketPtr++)
    {
    for (e = *hp;e ->next!= NULL;e = e->next) 
    fprintf(htfile,"\n%d \t%s",(e->fp).chunk_length,(e->fp).fing_print);        
    }
fclose(htfile);
}
```

my problem is (are)

1-it says "Access violation reading location 0xfdfdfe09." after writting a considerable number of times (it wrote 6401 fingerprints). It indicates the faulty line to be the fprintf() in the file writing function.

2- the fingerprints it writes and what i have before writing does not match at all. Actually the hex representation of the fingerprints in the compiler(i am using VC2010) and the one i have which is read by the program are different.

3- the values for chunck_length of all the entries are 3452816845l

Comment: `t->buck_entry_count[h & t->mask]++;` I cannot see t->mask initialised anywhere. Given that  "t->buck_entry_count[]" is fixed size (64) t->mask should be at most 0x3f, this line is at least suspect. Additional tip: use unsigned types for your indices, that will avoid negative indexing, and on errors, and in most cases, the program will fail faster, with less corruption.

Answer (score 1):

I guess the loop in `WriteHTtoFile` should look more like this:

```
for (i = 0; i < t->numBuckets; ++i)
{
    for (e = t->bucketPtr[i]; e && e->next; e = e->next) 
        fprintf(htfile, /*...*/);        
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have more problems than that; this code is hopelessly botched

- WriteHTToFile modifies the original hashtable, so you end up with memory leak at least
- You use `%d` format to print out `fing_print`; it's not at all clear what `fing_print` is/should be (binary string; ascii string).

Get a good book on C, and get some practice with a debugger.

Comment: please see edit, it was a typo error, finger_print is an ascii string; but can u tell me please where WriteHTToFile modifies the table?

Comment: sorry i don't have much experience in programming. can u tell me how to correct it so that it does not modify the original data?